# Splitted PDF Files are being duplicated when Splitted using Text - Python Script

Tags: python, pdf, split

I am trying to split 100 of PDFs with python by specific keyword.
If a page in Python contains that keyword, split that page into a new PDF.
The Problem i am facing is, the files are being duplicated. I have tried everything to stop the duplication process but it won't change.

```
import os
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

def split_pdf_by_text(pdf_path, keyword, output_folder):
    # Check if the provided path is a valid file
    if not os.path.isfile(pdf_path):
        print(f"Error: '{pdf_path}' is not a valid file.")
        return

    # Create output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    print(f"Processing PDF: {pdf_path}")

    # Open the PDF file
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)

    # Initialize a set to keep track of processed pages
    processed_pages = set()

    # Iterate through each page
    for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
        # Skip the page if it's already processed
        if page_number in processed_pages:
            continue

        # Get the page
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)

        # Extract text from the page
        text = page.get_text()

        # Check if the keyword exists in the page text
        if keyword in text:
            # Construct the output file path
            output_file_name = f"{os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]}_page_{page_number + 1}.pdf"
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, output_file_name)

            # Create a new PDF document
            new_pdf = fitz.open()
            new_pdf.insert_pdf(pdf_document, from_page=page_number, to_page=page_number)  # Insert the current page into the new PDF
            new_pdf.save(output_path)  # Save the new PDF

            print(f"Page {page_number + 1} saved to: {output_path}")

            # Close the new PDF
            new_pdf.close()

            # Add the page number to the set of processed pages
            processed_pages.add(page_number)

    # Close the original PDF
    pdf_document.close()

# Define the function to process all PDF files in a directory
def process_all_pdfs(input_folder, keyword, output_folder):
    # Iterate through each file in the input folder
    for root, _, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".pdf"):
                # Get the full path of the PDF file
                pdf_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                
                # Process the PDF file
                split_pdf_by_text(pdf_path, keyword, output_folder)
```

If a page was processed, I tried to skip it and move along to the next page, but it's not working out for me.

Comment: Unclear what you really want: copy all pages of all 100 files into separate 1-page documents if they contain a given keyword? If yes, then you don't need to check for page duplications (`processed_pages`), because page numbers are always ascending in each PDF. This approach I also wouldn't call "split": the original PDFs are not changed, are they?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import fitz
hundred_filenames = [...]

for filename in hundred_filenames:
    doc = fitz.open(filename)
    for page in doc:
        if page.search_for(keyword) != []:  # contains the keyword!
            out_name = f"{doc.name}-{page.number}.pdf"
            new = fitz.open()
            new.insert_pdf(doc, from_page=page.number, to_page=page.number)
            new.save(out_name)
            new.close()
    doc.close()
```

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).